# Not recognising this.state.data in ReactJs app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to build a simple Todo app, however throws an error:
Please can someone help identify the error??

**Error**

> app.min.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
>       at Object.value [as addNewContact] (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:9:18059)
>       at b.value (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:9:19043)
>       at Object.f.invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:3:5790)
>       at g (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:3:3021)
>       at Object.h [as executeDispatchesInOrder] (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:3:3241)
>       at l (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:2:30755)
>       at n (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:2:30881)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at c (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:3:6210)
>       at Object.processEventQueue (http://localhost:8888/dist/assets/js/app.min.js:2:31947

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export class ContactsListApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: this.props.data
        }
    }
    addContact(newContactObj) {
        console.log(newContactObj);
        var tmpStateData = this.state.data;
        tmpStateData.push(newContactObj.value);

        this.setState({
            data: tmpStateData
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="contact-list">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <AddContactPanel addNewContact={this.addContact} />
                            <ContactList contacts={this.state.data} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class ContactList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var items = Array.prototype.map.call(this.props.contacts, function (contact, index) {
            return <ContactItem name={contact.name} key={index} />
        });

        return (
            <ul>{items}</ul>
        )
    }
}

class AddContactPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    handleAddContact() {
        var contactItem = this.refs.newContactName;
        this.props.addNewContact({
            "_id": (Math.random(1000 * 10) + 1),
            "name": this.refs.newContactName.value,
            "occupation": "myJob",
            "email": "me@hotmail.com",
            "telephone": "0123456789"
        }); 
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <form>
                    <input required ref="newContactName" type="text" name="newContactName" />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" onClick={this.handleAddContact.bind(this)} />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class ContactItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.name}</li>
        )
    }
}


module.exports = {
    contactListApp: ContactsListApp
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set `this` for `addContact` - `this.addContact.bind(this)`

Comment: Also, in your `constructor` the initial value of the `data` key within the state should be set to `props.data` and not `this.props.data`

Answer (score 1):

**First of all** in order to make the state available to the function you need to bind it. You can make use of fat-arrow function for this purpose

```
addContact(newContactObj) {
        console.log(newContactObj);
        var tmpStateData = this.state.data;
        tmpStateData.push(newContactObj.value);

        this.setState({
            data: tmpStateData
        });
    }
```

**Secondly:** setting props to the initial state is an anti-pattern as suggested by [react docs](http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) and you should avoid using it this way. Instead you can set the state to a prop value in the componentDidMount function like

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: ''
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({data: this.props.data})
}
addContact = (newContactObj) => {
    console.log(newContactObj);
    var tmpStateData = this.state.data;
    tmpStateData.push(newContactObj.value);

    this.setState({
        data: tmpStateData
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works - appreciated! Do I have to use fat arrows? It would be great to show me without its use, noting alternative techniques in achieving the same result

Comment: Yes you can bind the function in constructor like. `this.addContact = this.addContact.bind(this)`